# Click a button to performclick() all buttons in ListView

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I have a `ListView` which every row (item) contains a `Button`. I implemented this button to download a file and it worked well. The next thing is I want to build a download all feature. To do this, I create a button which can click all the buttons in my listview at once but didn't work. I try to use the `performclick()` function but it only worked with the rows that visible on the screen. When I used the for loop to get all buttons in my `ListView` the app stopped working. How can I do to implement my download all `Button`?

This code worked well

```
buttonDownloadAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    // The visible rows are 0 to 5
                    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {                      
                        listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.lessonDownload).performClick();
                    }
                }
            });
```

This code didn't work

```
buttonDownloadAll.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
                        // This doesn't work & make the app stop working
                        listView.getChildAt(i).findViewById(R.id.lessonDownload).performClick();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Why you want  to perform click of all button? you can download your file using the list attached to the `listview`.

Comment: the thing is, i have set a progress circle appear to update download percentage, and a button to open file which visible after download is finished. These happens in my download button OnClickListener. I have to performclick these buttons to run those thing

Comment: I think you can modify your approach to execute this functionality. You have already created method download(URL) on particular List Item click. On Download all simply loop all your URL's and call this download(URL) method instead of calling all button click events. You can also maintain progress of this activity by passing status to UI before next call.

Comment: @Rohan amazing idea. I will try this approach